# Pandas to_csv drops rows (when writing to file-like object)

Tags: python, pandas

When using a `tempfile.TemporaryFile` as an intermediate to writing a pandas DF to csv (`to_csv`), some rows are silently dropped from the end of the DF.
The number of rows that is dropped depends on both the length and width of the DF, in a seemingly unpredictable manner.

Indeed, if the DF is short enough, ALL rows are dropped and an empty file results (no rows written to disk).

The evidence suggests that this is a bug in Pandas, but it is possible that I have an error in the pure Python code.

See code and results below (python 3.5, pandas 0.20

```
import shutil
from io import TextIOWrapper, BufferedWriter
from tempfile import TemporaryFile
import pandas as pd

def pd_bug(size, rep_str):
    out_path = "bug_{}_{}".format(rep_str, size)

    diags = {"str": [rep_str] * size, "num": [i for i in range(size)]}
    df = pd.DataFrame(diags)

    with TemporaryFile() as f, BufferedWriter(f) as bw, TextIOWrapper(bw) as iow:
        df.to_csv(iow, index=False)
        with open(out_path, "w+b") as t:
                f.seek(0)
                shutil.copyfileobj(f, t)
```

Results:

```
pd_bug(100, "abc")      # tail -n1 bug_abc_100      ->                <EMPTY>
pd_bug(1000, "abc")     # tail -n1 bug_abc_1000     ->                <EMPTY>
pd_bug(2000, "abc")     # tail -n1 bug_abc_2000     ->  1943,abc      <57 dropped>
pd_bug(5000, "abc")     # tail -n1 bug_abc_5000     ->  4676,abc      <324 dropped>
pd_bug(10000, "abc")    # tail -n1 bug_abc_10000    ->  9231,abc      <769 dropped>
pd_bug(50000, "abc")    # tail -n1 bug_abc_50000    ->  49488,abc     <512 dropped>

pd_bug(100, "pandas")   # tail -n1 bug_pandas_100   ->                <EMPTY>
pd_bug(1000, "pandas")  # tail -n1 bug_pandas_1000  ->  754,pandas    <46 dropped>
pd_bug(2000, "pandas")  # tail -n1 bug_pandas_2000  ->  1458,pandas   <542 dropped>
pd_bug(5000, "pandas")  # tail -n1 bug_pandas_5000  ->  4873,pandas   <127 dropped>
pd_bug(10000, "pandas") # tail -n1 bug_pandas_10000 ->  9654,pandas   <346 dropped>
pd_bug(50000, "pandas") # tail -n1 bug_pandas_50000 ->  49433,pandas  <567 dropped>
```

This only seems to occur using the file-like object; using the standard
`df.to_csv("/a/path/ok")` works fine -- no rows are dropped